# How to clear multiInput tokens in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

Hi I'm using this code to create a tokens in multiinput.

```
multiInput: function(){
           var oMultiInput1 = this.getView().byId("multiInputRep");
           oMultiInput1.addValidator(function(args){
                var text = args.text;
                return new sap.m.Token({key: text, text: text});                
            });         
        },
```

when I have to reset the tokens with this instruction

```
this.getView().byId('multiInputRep').removeAllTokens();
```

tokens they then clear but the string "Other ..." didn't hide...

Comment: this.getView().byId("multiInput").destroyTokens();

Comment: Thanks for you answer , I've already tried with this instruction the problem persist...

Comment: If you post your problem as a working fiddle/demo it will be more helpful.

Comment: Solved! The problem wasn't "removeAllTokens()",  i had forgotten to reset my model :)
Thanks a lot for your answers!